# Trying to run user-mode process from a local service with medium integrity level

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel32

My goal is to run my user GUI process in a logged on user session from my local service. I roughly do the following:

```
//Pseudo-code, with error checks omitted
HANDLE hToken;
WTSQueryUserToken(dwUserSessionID, &hToken);

HANDLE hToken2;
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken2);

//Need to adjust UIAccess for the needs of the user process
DWORD dwUIAccess = 1;
SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenUIAccess, &dwUIAccess, sizeof(dwUIAccess));

ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken2);

CreateProcessAsUser(hToken2, strUserExeFilePath, ...);

RevertToSelf();

CloseHandle(hToken2);
CloseHandle(hToken);
```

This works and the user process starts just fine, but there's one issue with its [integrity level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx). When this code runs right after the service is installed (when the user session has been long logged on) the user process it creates has `SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID`, which is the level I would expect.

But if the code above is run right after an interactive Windows user logs on to the workstation, the user process starts up but it has the `SECURITY_MANDATORY_HIGH_RID` integrity level. (I am testing it on Windows 7.)

So I thought to add the following code to adjust the integrity level:

```
PSID pSidIL = NULL;
//INFO on SID: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330?wa=wsignin1.0
ConvertStringSidToSid(L"S-1-16-8192", &pSidIL);

TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = {0};
tml.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY;
tml.Label.Sid = pSidIL;

SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, sizeof(TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL) + ::GetSidLengthRequired(1));

LocalFree(pSidIL);
```

but it made no difference, and the user process still ran with `high` integrity level after a user logon.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It sounds as if you're getting the elevated token rather than the restricted token.  As well as having high integrity level, does the process token also contain the Administrators group?

Comment: I don't think it affects primary tokens, but try SecurityImpersonation or SecurityDelegation instead of SecurityIdentification.

Comment: Also use GetTokenInformation to check the value of TokenElevationType.  It might even be TokenElevationTypeDefault, meaning that the original token has not yet been converted into a pair of linked tokens.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: First off thanks for looking into it. I tried to check `S-1-5-32-544` group membership with `CheckTokenMembership(hToken2, ,)` but it fails with `ERROR_NO_IMPERSONATION_TOKEN`. I also tried calling it within `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` and it failed with the same error as well. So that may be a clue, although I don't really know where to go from there... As for different `ImpersonationLevel` then it made no difference. And lastly the `hToken2` has `TokenElevationTypeLimited` elevation type, as I would expect it.

Comment: I'm assuming that I can lower my own impersonation level from my user process, correct? If so, I'll probably resort to that workaround.

Comment: I don't think so.  Not comprehensively, at any rate.  The problem with CheckTokenMembership is that it only works on impersonation tokens, not primary tokens.  Try passing `NULL` for the first argument, after ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken2).

Comment: Have you tried checking the integrity level of hToken and of hToken2?  It would be useful to know whether the integrity is wrong immediately, whether it goes wrong after the duplication, or whether it doesn't go wrong until copied into the new process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Oh, shoot. I just realized something after having worked on this for over a day... that user process wasn't launched by my service, but instead was autorun from the `HKLM\...\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key. Ding it! Now the question is why Explorer running it at high integrity level? but I'll have to start a separate thread for that. Sorry for misleading everyone. I'll delete this post.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Windows to me. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Just so that I understand this mandatory integrity level thing -- is it "better" that a user process runs with lower or higher MIL?

Comment: The more trusted the process, the higher the integrity.  Having a non-elevated process with high integrity is odd - but on second thoughts perhaps not actually dangerous.  (Having an elevated process with medium or low integrity would be dangerous.)  It might not be a bug, could be intentional.

Comment: Yes, that's correct my user process runs non-elevated but with high MIL. So in that case, this seems like a "good" thing. Appreciate your help!